# How do I validate group of checkboxes in Primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I have 4 selectBooleanCheckBoxes in my page. How do I make sure that atleast one of them is check during form submission?

Is there a way to achieve this using custom validator class?

Comment: Use the custom server side (bean level) validation, called from your form submission action listener.

Comment: I had implemented it already. but Is there any other way than that?

Comment: The other way around is to validate on client side using custom script.

Comment: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateMultiple

Comment: validateMultiple seems to be my solution :)

Comment: @JasperdeVries http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateOneOrMore is the better match :-)

Comment: Sidenode: I'm not quite sure, but I think a simple validator might not be enough, as a checkbox can't have an "empty" state. It's either checked or not, both are valid submissions. (Theres a RequiredCheckBoxValidator by omnifaces, but not sure if that can be combined with `validateOneOrMore`)

Comment: Sidenode 2: okay, `validateOneOrMore` does not support a custom validator. So for Checkboxes, `validateMultiple` might be better as you can provide your own `validator`.